# How to source/include small gdb script in main gdb script?

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I have *main.gdb* located in *~/gdbTest/main.gdb* which contains some functions. Also, I have few other gdb scripts e.g. *func1.gdb*, *func2.gdb* in same folder. I am trying to include these scripts in *main.gdb* as follows.

*main.gdb*

```
  source ./func1.gdb  
  source ./func2.gdb
```

However this is not working. (Note that I have sourced main.gdb in ~/.gdbinit and want only main.gdb to be sourced in ~/.gdbinit  ).
So,how can I solve this issue? Is there any alternate way to handle such issue?

Comment: '.' is the process current directory, not the file

Comment: yes, func1.gdb and all other scripts are present in same directory where main.gdb is present e.g. ~/gdbTest/

Comment: Find the pid of gdb and do `ls -l /proc<pid>/cwd`.  That's where '.' is.

Comment: You can put `directory ~/gdbTest` in your .gdbinit. It will add that directory to the search path for sourced scripts (which will help you here) and  for source code for the target (which you may not want). After that command, you can run `source main.gdb`, `source func1.gdb`, etc.